# When MFMailComposeViewController doesn't work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, email, device

In which situations a MFMailComposeViewController wouldn't work on iOS 4?

For example, does it work when the user hasn't set up an account in Apple's Mail app? And is there any other situation where it won't work, because a user complained it didn't work and he had iOS 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no account is set up, the `MFMailComposeViewController` cannot work. You can call `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` to check if the user has at least one mail account configured and enabled. As far as I know, it does not check if the user's device is set up properly (i.e. no check for correct username and password etc.). In short: If the Mail app works, your `MFMailComposeViewController` is going to work as well. If it does not, you will need to give a more detailed description of the problem than "does not work".

Comment: By the way: `+canSendMail` will return `NO` if there is an enabled account, but if none is configured for _sending_ emails.